# Passing an API parameter to url laravel/guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, guzzle

I have a simple controller that consumes an API(OpenWeatherMap) with guzzle and generates a get request upon entry. However I would like that my zipcode parameter not be hardcoded within the codebase but can be dynamic and can be called through the URL. Please see reference code.

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class GuzzleController extends Controller
{
    public  function index()
{

    try {

        $client = new Client([
    // Base URI is used with relative requests
            'base_uri' => 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/',
        ]);

        $response = $client->request('GET', 'forecast', [
            'query' => [
                'zip' => '32811',
                'country code' => 'us',
                'APPID' => '02f129190a8736e107260eadce1d781e'

            ],

        ]);

        if($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
            return $response->getBody()->getContents();

        }
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('forecast', 'GuzzleController@index');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exists two ways for achieving this.

1. With a query string parameter

URL: `app.tld/forecast?zip=32811`

Your controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    ...

    $response = $client->request('GET', 'forecast', [
        'query' => [
            'zip' => $request->input('zip'),
            'country code' => 'us',
            'APPID' => '02f129190a8736e107260eadce1d781e'
        ],
    ]);

    ...
}
```

2. With nicer URLs:

URL: `app.tld/forecast/32811` (32811 is the ZIP code)

Your route:

```
Route::get('forecast/{zip}', 'GuzzleController@index');
```

Your controller:

```
public function index(string $zip)
{
    ...

    $response = $client->request('GET', 'forecast', [
        'query' => [
            'zip' => $zip,
            'country code' => 'us',
            'APPID' => '02f129190a8736e107260eadce1d781e'
        ],
    ]);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, both methods work! I am actually going to take this bit of logic and create a composer package that can be pulled in and anyone can use. But just doing stuff to build on my resume